# MobileIron enabled app network requests failing after a while - host not found errors. Using app tunnelling

Tags: ios, mobileiron

I'm doing a MobileIron integration for an iPad app that will be distributed via MobileIron. The app uses the AppConnect SDK. This is all setup and working as expected.

Normally, network requests to production URLs work fine. They have been whitelisted for the configuration, firewalls opened, etc. However, after some time elapses (usually after about an hour of launching/re-launching) the requests start to fail. The error in iOS is specifically kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost -1003.

The only workaround is to re-install from scratch or do a force check-in. However the error comes back after a while.

The Mobile Iron app > Settings > Secure Apps > "the app" shows AppTunnel as "None". Don't know if this is important or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your Settings are showing AppTunnel as None, then you are not accessing any resources through a secure app tunnel. It appears that the application may be using MI simply or distribution, which is fine, but the mobile application would not need the MI SDK at all. What features of the AppConnect SDK are being used? The 1003 error is most likely a port/connection getting closed at some interval on the target host.

Comment: We actually switched from MI test to production environment and we no longer get the connection errors. Also notice that the configuration now shows AppTunnel is working (it's not "none").